# A view that appends new tables dynamically in SQL (SSMS)

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, view, append

I have a history of tables that were created and will be created monthly. 
They look like `mytable_201501`, `mytable_201502` and so on until `mytable`, which is the last table in time terms. So since we are in May, `mytable` will become `mytable_202004` in June, while new `mytable` will have data for May. Not sure if there is a word for this kind of setup.

Now I need to create a view, that would append all of these queries into one.

My current code is a simple

```
CREATE VIEW
SELECT * FROM mytable_201501 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM mytable_201502 
...
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM mytable
```

This takes a lot of space and has to be updated each month. 
I'm looking for a way to automate this if there is one in SQL.

Comment: So create a job that runs every day and looks for a "new" table. If one is found, it alters the view.

Comment: Or change the process that creates that table to alter the view as a final step

Comment: Have you considered using a partitioned table - partitioned by month - instead of multiple separate tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate the view definition by querying sys.tables, like this:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 
(
    select '
    create or alter view v_mytable
    as
    '+ STRING_AGG( 'select * from ' + quotename(name) ,'
    union all 
    ')
    from sys.tables
    where name like 'mytable%'
)
print @sql 

--exec (@sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

A word for this type of setup?  "Broken".

You should have a single table for *all* months, with a column specifying the month.  For performance, you can partition the table by the month column.  Then your query is quite simple.  It can query the months it wants.

Once upon a time, SQL Server did not support real partitioning and tables needed to be "sharded" (for lack of a better term) and then combined using `union all`.  That time is long past.

Given your situation, I would suggest that you do the following:

- Create a new table just like the old tables with an additional columns for the "effective date" or "load date" or whatever, partitioning by this column if appropriate.
- Load the table with all existing data.
- Modify the job that creates the table for each month and insert into this table.

Instead of modifying the job, you can also use a DDL trigger, although I recommend changing the job.

Comment: And for some time after partitioning was introduced, it was limited to Enterprise Edition. 
But since SQL Server 2016 SP1, Partitioned Tables and Indexes have been available in all editions of SQL Server and Azure SQL Database. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/partitions/partitioned-tables-and-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15